# Fix issues jQuery UI Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

here's the link to my dialog ([click here](http://dev.tasch.co.za/mydialog/asctDialog.html))

I tried to fix the below in order to referring to the official website dialog ([click here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)) but I can't find how to do that:

**I need to :**

- bring back the cross sign (x) at right side of the dialog,
- and add the small exclamation image,
- change background color of the title frame only,
- and buttons (**Delete all items** & **Cancel**), the frame that surrounds them must be like [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) (with space "High, Down, Left, Right").

Comment: add some code. Make JSfiddle. Don't post links to sites that look suspicious

Comment: Provided [Official Website Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) is working properly. 1) Check your `console` for any **JS** errors. 2) Check given **CDNs** included properly. 3) Check any other **CSS** reflect or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the chrome dev tools, it seems you image files for icons are not loading.[image]

Sort this out and this will fix your icon problems (close button and exclamation image).

Set what ever color you want using following css.

```
.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background: red;
}
```

For Dialog buttons use following css

```
.ui-button {
    padding: .4em 1em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. But I still have one concern : I'm using online CSS & jQuery links that loads according to Internet bandwidth. Please see below `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`. So if I tried to save them in local and link them to the project but when I load the page, it doesn't display correctly.  How do I fix that problem???